# Seems like windowAnimationStyle is being ignored, how to animate custom dialog?

Tags: android, animation

I wish to animate my custom dialog as appearing from a specific point but I am having trouble setting animation to the dialog.

The dialog is a basic `RelativeLayout` set as layout within a class that `extends` `Dialog`.

As some answers here suggested I have tried setting `windowAnimations` to it like

```
final myCustomDialog dialog = new myCustomDialog(this); 
dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.CustomDialogTheme;
```

EDIT: setting theme in constructor seems to be working but the animations still don't work

```
final myCustomDialog dialog = new myCustomDialog(this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

CustomDialogTheme style being

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="PauseDialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

It just doesn't work, has no effect. I tried setting the same in `android:windowAnimationStyle` to the project theme and that worked for the activity.

What am I doing wrong and how do I animate a custom dialog if this doesn't work anymore.

Testing on Android 4.4.4 Paranoid Android with all animations set to 1x and Genymotion simulator for Nexus 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing your dialog passing the style on the constructor like this:

```
final myCustomDialog dialog = new myCustomDialog(this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Comment: it did seem to affect the look but didn't work for animations.

Comment: never mind, forgot to remove a line setting attributes and now it works. :)

Comment: Lol it happens :P
Please mark the answer as correct